# What's the relationship between ~foo~ and =foo= in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Both `=foo=` and `~foo~` seem to be used in org for inline bits of code. How do they differ? Which should I use, and when?

For example, from the `ORG-NEWS` file:

```
If you want to exclude a headline from export while using its contents
for setting options, use =:noexport:= (see =org-export-exclude-tags=.)

...

The key sequences =C-c C-n= and =C-c C-p= are now bound to
~org-next-visible-heading~ and ~org-previous-visible-heading~ respectively,
rather than the =outline-mode= versions of these functions.  The Org
version of these functions skips over inline tasks (and even-level
headlines when ~org-odd-levels-only~ is set).
```

There isn't an obvious pattern here: `org-export-exclude-tags` and `org-odd-levels-only` are both variables, and `org-next-visible-heading` and `outline-mode` are both functions.

Do either of these syntaxes support jumping to `*Help*` buffers the way `` `foo' `` does in docstrings?

Comment: I have had the same question for many years. I ended up never using `~ .. ~`, and instead using `= .. =`  for everything verbatim, including inline code snippets.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991981/difference-between-code-and-verbatim-in-org-mode for the difference when exporting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Org info page on "Emphasis and monospace" we have

```
`=verbatim=' and `~code~'
```

In your examples the functions and variables are pieces of elisp code, so `~...~` is appropriate.  The uses of `=...=` you cite are for key sequences and text for the user to place in the `org` buffer, i.e. markup rather than code.  However, the markup of `=outline-mode=` is borderline between the two categories.

Answer (score 3):

It's suitable to interpretation. I've been redefining e.g. `~C-f~` to
export to `<kbd>C-f</kbd>` in HTML, and e.g. `=forward-char=` to
`<code>forward-char</code>`.

```cl
(setq org-html-text-markup-alist
      '((bold . "<b>%s</b>")
        (code . "<kbd>%s</kbd>")
        (italic . "<i>%s</i>")
        (strike-through . "<del>%s</del>")
        (underline . "<span class=\"underline\">%s</span>")
        (verbatim . "<code>%s</code>")))
```

But their default names are indeed `code` and `verbatim`, just like the other answer says.